# How to connect to ec2 instance using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-ssm

I have an ec2 instance running which is used to run sql command to get results from a rds residing into private subnet. Using python-boto3 I want to connect to ec2 instance using session manager and run few queries

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What is your _specific_ issue that you are facing? AWS Systems Manager Session Manager provides an interactive connection to an instance (similar to SSH). You would _not_ use it if making a programmatic connection from a Python program. Would it be correct to assume that you want to run SQL queries from your own computer on the Internet, but it needs to go via the EC2 instance to access the RDS database in a private subnet? Have you considered using Port Forwarding to connect to the database via the instance?

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Thnaks!